# C# GraphX highlight vertex on click

Tags: c#, wpf, graphx-net

I'm using [GraphX for .NET](https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX) and I'm trying to **highlight** a vertex when the user clicks on it.

I registered for the `VertexSelected` event:

```cs
public class MyGraphArea : GraphArea<Node, Edge, MiniFlowGraph>
{
    public MyGraphArea()
    {
        VertexSelected += VertexSelected_MarkVertex;
    }

    private void VertexSelected_MarkVertex(object sender,VertexSelectedEventArgs args)
    {
        HighlightBehaviour.SetHighlighted(args.VertexControl, true);
    }
}
```

But nothing happened in the UI. So I tried to add multiple options:

To the constructor I added:

```cs
EnableVisualPropsApply = true;
HighlightBehaviour.SetIsHighlightEnabled(this, true);
SetVerticesHighlight(true, GraphControlType.VertexAndEdge);
```

I also registered to the `Loaded` event and added this code:

```cs
foreach (var item in VertexList)
    HighlightBehaviour.SetIsHighlightEnabled(item.Value, true);
```

Then I added the line `SetVerticesHighlight(true, GraphControlType.VertexAndEdge)` to the `VertexSelected` event, just for case.

But nothing happened.

I'm looking at the [source code](https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX/blob/PCL/Examples/ShowcaseApp.WPF/Pages/DynamicGraph.xaml.cs), and I can't find anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to add the following lines of code:

```
Graph.SetEdgesHighlight(true, GraphControlType.VertexAndEdge);
Graph.SetVerticesHighlight(true, GraphControlType.VertexAndEdge, EdgesType.All);
```

I was playing around with the WindowsFormsProject example, and I added these lines just before the return statement of the method `Form1.GenerateWpfVisuals()`. I did not had to subscribe to any event. However, the standard behavior will highlight vertices and edges on mouse hover, not on mouse click.

The default `Gold` color is used for the highlighting is defined in `template.xaml`:

```
<!-- VERTEX CONTROL -->
...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="controls:HighlightBehaviour.Highlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="7"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

...

```
<!-- EDGE CONTROL -->
...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="controls:HighlightBehaviour.Highlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```